# Custom Create new view

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic

[image]
i need to replicate the custom create new view functionality,after selecting the condition i have to store the data in to some object .is this possible to achieve the functionality??Could you please is there any other way to achieve the functionality

Comment: you will need to go with VF for this

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve involves a lot of developing using Apex/VisualForce but if I had to do the requirement I would start by implementing AND/OR/NOT logic. That will give you the foundation and the platform you need to put together the conditions. You can find some examples [here](http://apex-commons.github.io/query/soql-builder/)

Once you implement that you need to use some describe methods to get the fields for the object you want to sort/query etc. You can find documentation here:

[Describe calls](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_list_describe.htm)

[Understanding Apex Describe Information](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm)

Also keep in mind that you have limits for describes as well. With those sorted you then need to put them into a controller and call the various methods from the SOQL builder and the describe methods and build the view in VisualForce.

Good luck

Comment: Suppose i use case objects fields in dropdown and after selecting the filter condition ,i need to put that data into one different object dynamically,Is it possible using Describe calls.

Comment: If moving data from the Case object to another custom object based on some criteria that will not be done regularly is what you need than I advise researching on some data migration tools for Salesforce, especially Data Loader. You will not need to replicate the view screen. Your question was about how you can replicate the functionality of the new view screen.